# VS Code Java Debugger

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I installed [VS Code Java Debugger](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-debug) and loaded my Java project.

Add Configuration:
[image]

I tried to add configuration by clicking the button as shown in above image.

Activating Extensions:
[image]

When I click Add Configuration, I get Activating Extensions like above and that's it.

Sometimes I get "The Language Support for Java crashed 5 times in the last 3 mins."

How do I setup the Java Debugger in VSCode?

**Note :** I Uninstalled VSCode, deleted the extensions from %Users%/.vscode/extensions and reinstalled VSCode and extensions. The issue still exists.

Comment: Add Images in your Question instead of link

Comment: I think new users cannot add images in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the following actions fixed this issue:

1. Un-install all Java related extensions.
2. Re-install the `Java Extension Pack` only.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same kind of error but one day found a solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61806765/5108695

Basic idea is to:
Install an extension called Lombok Annotations

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GabrielBB.vscode-lombok

After installation of this extension, my Java code is able to run and debug in VSCode.

PS: Make sure you had insalled Java Extension pack
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack