# The Language Support for Java server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted

Tags: java, android, flutter, visual-studio-code

After added gitlab, my flutter project is not working vs code not run the Android app. so, I restart my Linux pc and tried again now it is showing this error message

> The Language Support for Java server crashed 5 times in the last 3
>   minutes. The server will not be restarted.

Any idea how to solve this?

> Could not find an option named "track-widget-creation".
>
> Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter  -h') for available flutter
>   commands and options. Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code
>   1

Comment: The problem is most likely explained by the "some error" that you didn't explain properly.

Comment: question updated please check

Comment: Need more information.  See my previous comment.

Comment: You may want to go over some of the results a google search would provide. There have been issues like this reported on github and some have solutions. This one seemed to work after a reinstall: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/828

Answer (score 13):

try this ;-
clean the workspace directory in the following way:

1. Open the command palette (F1)
2. select Java: Clean the Java Language Server Workspace
3. select Restart and delete from the confirmation prompt

Answer (score 11):

I was facing the same issue, struggled a lot but no success
One day I was just looking for some threads and found a solution.

Install an extension called `Lombok Annotations`

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GabrielBB.vscode-lombok

After installation of this extension, my Java code is able to run and debug in VSCode.

PS:
Make sure you had insalled Java Extension pack
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack

Comment: None of this solved the issue for me. I'm using VS v 19 on Mac. I have Java Extension Pack, Java Language Support, Lombok Annotation, Java Debugger extensions installed. I try to create a Spring starter project. It gives me between 6-8 errors as soon as the project is created. I then try to Java clean. It still has the same errors (Java 134217868, 16777540,134217868, 963, 16777218). I keep reading posts about how VS should be configured 'correctly' but can't find any instruction on what that means or how to configure it to use Java.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I tried several solutions like cleaning the workspace, installing the Lombok Annotation extension. But none of them worked. Then I tried the following:-

- I cleaned the Java Language Server Workspace and uninstalled the java extension pack.
- I restarted my laptop and again installed the java extension pack.
  It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved after downloading JDK 11 and setting the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

1. Download JDK 11 from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html)
2. In `.bash_profile` add the following line.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/your/jdk
```

3. Restart your computer.